# Why doesn't qTip tooltip  stay open so I can click link on it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, qtip

Here is my [example](http://jsfiddle.net/53jQS/) in jsfiddle, hover over Minnesota to see the qtip popup. I am using  [qTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/demos/) jquery plugin and I am getting stuck on making the qtip stay around long enough for someone to click the link on the tooltip. I have tried all kinds on scenerios to make it stay open. Reading the [documentation](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/docs/) it seems to be easy to do so but I tried these and no luck. I tried these

```
hide: { when: 'mouseout', fixed: true }
```

and

```
hide: { fixed: true, delay: 1000 }
```

and many others and nothing will keep the tooltip up so the user can click on a link. The thing that is irritating is that on the [reference](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/docs/reference/) page. If you click on any of the example links they are doing exactly what i want to do and i went to the source and if seems that they are using

```
  hide: 'unfocus',
```

and

```
     hide: {
        fixed: true,
        delay: 240
     },
```

but I tried both and the tooltip won't stay open. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since it appears the position of your tip is off to the right some, try this:

```
  $(this).qtip(
  {
      hide:{ //moved hide to here,
        delay:500, //give a small delay to allow the user to mouse over it.
        fixed:true
      },
     content: $("." + test).html(),
     style: {
        name: 'dark',
         style: {
            border: 1,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            padding: '5px 8px',
            name: 'blue'
         },
        border: {}, 
        tip: true // Apply a tip at the default tooltip corner
     }
  });
```

**Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/53jQS/4/).**

Answer (score 1):

You've  got 2 styles in your code and it's just all sorts of wonky. Here is your code, working.

http://jsfiddle.net/JDVTM/